# couldn't find path

Tags: c#, csv, xamarin.forms

I'm getting this error when I try to open the file.The file path does exist i copied from the explorer to make sure there was no error in the path string.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   "/C:\Users\Mario\Documents\ativita\ativita\produtos_20180713.CSV"

```
List <banco_produtos> csv = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\Users\\Mario\\Documents\\ativita\\ativita\\produtos_20180713.CSV"))
                       .Skip(1)
                       .Select(c => c.Split(','))
                       .Select(x => new //there some code here 

                       })
```

Comment: Why are you calling `Path.GetDirectoryName`?

Comment: if this is a Xamarin app, then it cannot read a file that is located on the desktop.  It can only read files that are located in the file system of the device/emulator that they are running on.

Comment: @mjwills If this is Xamarin the target may be a Unix-like system, in which case I can plausibly see `Path.GetDirectoryName` putting a `/` on the start of a Windows-style path.

Comment: there is no "/" before the C the code is adding it.

Comment: @Jason and how I get the file path if I put inside the emulator? I can do the same as win"c:\\Users" but the path inside the emultator?

Comment: You need to copy the file into your project at build time, or read it from a server at runtime.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin

Comment: Possible duplicates [stack overflow - xamarin.forms load file](https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin.forms+load+file+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I have found the answer in this link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043058/xamarin-forms-read-from-text-file-result-is-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48043058/xamarin-forms-read-from-text-file-result-is-null)

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have given the full path and you should remove `Path.GetDirectoryName` from your code:

```
   banco_produtos[] csv = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Mario\\Documents\\ativita\\ativita\\produtos_20180713.CSV")
                           .Skip(1)
                           .Select(c => c.Split(','))
                           .Select(x => new //there some code here 

                           });
```

2- `ReadAllLines()`, returns an array not a list so either you have to use `banco_produtos[] csv` or use `.ToList()` to convert it to a List.

Comment: I do use ".ToList()" at the end.

Comment: @Mario Great. I just wanted to make sure that code will work for you. Please upvote and mark as answer if it helped.

Comment: This makes no sense. The biggest problem in here is that the path points to a Windows system and we are talking about mobile here. This is never going to work like this.

Comment: Well what I'm doing here is to show correct way of using `File.ReadAllLines()`

Answer (score -3):

Seems like this is a problem with characters not being escaped. Try setting the path to a variable, then pass in the variable to your `GetDirectoryName` call.

Try:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Mario\Documents\ativita\ativita\";


List <banco_produtos> csv = File.ReadAllLines(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
                       .Skip(1)
                       .Select(c => c.Split(','))
                       .Select(x => new //there some code here 

                       })
```

Comment: You can't read lines from a *file* if you pass the name of a *directory* in.  `Path.GetDirectoryName` should be removed *entirely*.  The OP did escape their path correctly.

Comment: what I'm doing right now is using the comment from @jason and did this.Added the file to the project and embended to the resource and the code:
`var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(novo_produto)).Assembly;
                
                Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ativita.Class1.txt");`
but now "stream" returns null.

Comment: Edited my comment to reflect a directory instead of a file. My mistake for not realizing OP was trying to read lines from a "file" using `Path.GetDirectoryName`. Was confused as to what OP was after.